# Do you include the sitemap on your storyboard?

Tags: navigation

I have designed my website layout which includes all my pages. The pages are all linked to the home page. I also have a site map included in my website. Do I include it in the layout as well?  It looks like this so far:

[image]

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking here. Are you saying that you have a sitemap *page* and want to know if you should show a reference to that page in your sitemap diagram?

Comment: @JonW exactly! Should I include the sitemap page as well?

Answer (score 1):

What I see here is pretty much a static website, with a few pages. Everything links to everything in a click or two.

I don't think many people will be able to use this sitemap to help understand potential flows to various pages, so for that reason, I would leave it out or change it.

If you change it, think about your goal. Who is this for? What do you want to convey? You stated that this is your website, so maybe it is just for your own personal organization/understanding of the structure of the site.

One suggestion would be to layout a few paths to certain content/actions.

eg. How can someone contact a writer?

1. Home ---> Writers --->Individual writer page --> contact writer
2. Home---> Novels ----(click writer)---> Contact writer.

etc...

Hope this helps.